# Socket losses connection after "Socket.Receive" function

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a c# client. The client's task is to log in to the server.

The issue is:
When I want to log in, I use a TCP socket which is created when the "wpf" window is initialized. After sending data using the socket once, everything is ok but when I want to send data again, using the same socket, this exception pops up:

System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.'

After some testing, I found out that the problem is caused by the Socket.Receive function. I checked the socket before the function was called, and the socket was connected (Socket.Connected == true), after returning from the function, the socket wasn't connected (Socket.Connected == false)

```
private static Socket ConnectSocket(string server, int port)
{
Socket s = null;
// Get host related information.
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);

// Loop through the AddressList to obtain the supported AddressFamily.
foreach (IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
{       
    //attempting to connect.
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
            //making a temp socket to check the connection (if something went wronge/ the server isnt active)
            Socket tempSocket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        // attempting connection.
        tempSocket.Connect(ipe);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request timed out");
            }

            //if we connected to the server, we are ok to continue.
            if (tempSocket.Connected)
            {
                s = tempSocket;
                break;
            }
            //else the connection isnt successful (the server might not respond) we need to try again.
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
}
Globals.SOCKET = s;
return s;
}

//This func will send a request to the server and returns the server's response.
public static string SocketSendReceive(string server, int port, string request, Socket socket = null)
{
    Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
    Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];
    string response = "";
    // Create a socket connection with the specified server and port.
    if (socket == null)
        socket = ConnectSocket(server, port);
    using (socket)
    {
        // If the connection faild and couldnt maintain a socket.
               if (socket.Connected == false)
            return ("Connection failed");

        // Send request to the server.
        socket.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);

                // Receiving the packet from the server.
                int bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length,0);//***The problem occures Here***
               response = response + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
    }
    return response;
}
```

the second function is the one that sends and receives data from the server.
the first one is just connecting and creating a socket

Thanks for your help! 
-Anthon

Comment: `using(socket)` means the socket will be disposed at the end of the `using` block... You should probably not be `using(socket)` here, because the function doesn't "own" the socket you passed in. This will work on the first call, all subsequent calls (and uses of `socket`) will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Change

socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length,0)

To

socket.Receive(bytesReceived, 0,  bytesReceived.Length)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Problem was the "using (socket) {}" scope. If you remove it, everything works.

Comment: That's not true, you can look at MSDN. func(char[] buffer, int size, sokcetFlag)